# Iphone sdk, How to post data to web server? anybody has example?

Tags: iphone, xcode

guys, I want to post data to web server, like username and password, on the web server, I used PHP to echo yes or no, I attached all the code. Can anybody help me out, what is wrong with the code. Since it always says incorrect password or username. I tried to test the php code with username and password inside, it is working. So please help me. Thank you.

Header file

```
@interface kiksyloginViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
    IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *usernameField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *passwordField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *loginButton;

- (IBAction) login: (id) sender;

@end
```

Implementation file

```
#import "kiksyloginViewController.h"

@implementation kiksyloginViewController

@synthesize usernameField;
@synthesize passwordField;
@synthesize loginButton;

- (IBAction) login: (id) sender
{

    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text];

    NSString *hostStr = @"http://localhost/userlogin.php";
    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
    NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];


    if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){

        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorized "
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Username or Password Incorrect"
                                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];

    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn’t have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren’t in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

PHP file

```
<?php 
//$Container = new Container; 

$u = $_GET['username']; 
$pw =$_GET['password']; 
$check = "select username, password from user where username='$u' and password='$pw'"; 
function myDbconn() 

{ 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(); 
    mysql_select_db("test") or die (mysql_error()); 
} 

myDbconn(); 


$login = mysql_query($check) or die (mysql_error()); 
//$run = DB()->select($check); 



if (mysql_num_rows($login)==1){ 
    //$row = DB()->fetch($run); 
    //$row = DB()->fetch($login); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login); 
    echo 'yes'; 
    exit;         
} 
else { 
    echo 'No'; 
    exit; 
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first issue I see that's probably the biggest is that there's no "?" anywhere.  Specifically, this:

```
@"username=%@&password=%@"
```

should look more like this:

```
@"?username=%@&password=%@"
```

Because you're not actually posting to the server, you're just using a GET request and URL parameters.

I don't know if you plan on getting a web server and PHP running on your device in the background, but at some point I assume you will change http://localhost to something else, and hopefully you will sanitize your SQL query before you let people navigate to your webpage and type in anything they want in the URL query.

Answer (score 1):

The post is old, but anyway if it may help others:

Yeah, it had a couple of errors. First, the correct string in file .m should be:

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?&username=%@&password=%@",
                 usernameField.text, passwordField.text];
```

Also at file .m:

```
if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"yes"]){
```

instead of "Yes". Be aware of capital letters!

That´s all. The code worked well.